# How to upgrade primefaces 4.0 to 6.2

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm new to primefaces. Currently my project using :
primefaces 4.0
jsf version 2.1.22
using eclipse for development.

But our client request to make upgrading to version 6.2
so, i make change primefaces version inside pom.xml
but, i dont know where is other place to make the change. I know maybe there is some code need to change in web.xml but i don't know where to refer on this. Can someone help me at least guide me where the place for me to refer for upgrade the primefaces version. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do migration is follow the instructions from set of migration guides on official PrimeFaces site: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/../migrationguide/migrationguide

Comment: does it mean that we need to migrate step by step?
mean that from version 4.0 --> 5.0

after success, then migrate from 5.0 --> 6.0
then 6.0 --> 6.1
and lastly 6.1 --> 6.2

is like that?

Comment: Dont validate if its sucessfull, just apply all changes